# Expanding parent's height when expanding's child height

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I am using this ExpandableView component https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/ExpandableView

which has a main class: https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/ExpandableView/blob/master/ExpandableViewProject/expandableview/src/main/java/com/expandable/view/ExpandableView.java

The component wraps other custom components specified by the user. When the custom components have fixed height, everything works fine.

However, I am creating a custom component which has a dynamic number of rows. Suppose this is the initial state:

```
this is row1
this is row2
this is row3
button
```

when I click the button, it will show

```
this is row1
this is row2
this is row3
this is row4
button
```

When I test my component in a LinearLayout, there is not problem and the new rows are shown. However, when I embed my custom component in ExpandableView, the ContentView of ExpandableView does not extend to wrap the new rows but instead, the button is hidden at the bottom.

I guess that to allow ExpandableView's ContentView to dynamically extend according to the size of the inner custom component I should implement onMeasure() method of ExpandableView. But so far, all my tests have being failed.

The hierarchy of my custom component is:

- top
- ...
- ExpandableView (extension of RelativeLayout, no onMeasure method)
- LinearLayout (defined in XML)
- ExpandableView (extension of RelativeLayout, no onMeasure method)
- My custom component (WeekTimes, extension of LinearLayout, no onMeasure method)

Any idea?

---

I guess this is a bug in ExpandableView component but do not know how to fix it.

Further detail: this is the code for instantiating ExpandableView:

```
    ExpandableView expandableContract = (ExpandableView) formsContained.findViewById(R.id.expandable_academy);
    expandableContract.fillData(R.drawable.button_selected_full, getStringResource(R.string.about_academy), false);
    expandableContract.addContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_offer_form_academy, new ExpandableView(this), true));
```

where R.layout.activity_offer_form_academy is just a layout with my component:

```
<com.dynassets.assets.util.weektimes.WeekTimes
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/weektimes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and the code of my custom component is

```
public class WeekTimes extends LinearLayout {

    public WeekTimes(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public WeekTimes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        Button button = new Button(getContext());
        button.setText("click me");
        addView(button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Button button = new Button(getContext());
                    button.setText("click me2");
                    addView(button);
                    requestLayout();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("MyApp", "exception", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, how to tell the parent ExpandableView to extend according to the children's height? Is this a matter of creating a onMeasure() method?

Comment: Please post the code, which you tried!

Comment: posted but quite lost on creating onMeasure() method on parent ExpandableView component to resize by itself when child's height resize dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was that ExpandableView contained an animation and this animation was fixing the height preventing the android layouts work as expected. Here is described in further detail:

https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/ExpandableView/issues/5

So the fix is reassigning the height to a relative value after the animation has ended. Issue is fixed by adding these new lines on the ExpandableView extension on the animation method:

```
animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        // release height
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = contentLayout.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        contentLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
});
```